# remove duplicate files python

Tags: python, duplicates

Can anyone help me out with:
Currently I have 1000 text files, each file is 100kb, but there are files that are similar or nearly identical, how do I remove duplicate files?
(it's best to use python)
I have a way, but it's not good.
I count the words in the text then compare
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/19L5iFC2D9fmhZJvZfFUoW1xiEwpeVXJP?usp=sharing
Sorry my english is not good

Comment: You'll need to write code, which you have apparently not even attempted to do.

Comment: "Similar", "nearly identical" and "duplicate" are different things. You'll need to decide on the criteria that you'll use to determine which (if any) files need to be deleted. Then you'll need to write some code.

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/19L5iFC2D9fmhZJvZfFUoW1xiEwpeVXJP?usp=sharing

Comment: I have a way, but it's not good

Comment: I count the words in the text then compare

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove_duplicates(dir):
    unique = []
    for filename in os.listdir(dir):
        if os.path.isfile(filename):
            filehash = md5.md5(file(filename).read()).hexdigest()
            if filehash not in unique: 
                unique.append(filehash)
            else: 
                os.remove(filename)
```

keep all files in one directory and use this code to remove duplicate files

Comment: thank you. This way deletes duplicate files, it doesn't solve the whole problem

Comment: ok  i will send u more code ok

Answer (score 0):

Since they're text file, I think you should read contents as strings then compare them. If you have no concern about time, just compare one by one.Or go find a tool which can extra the token of string.

This [article](https://medium.com/@adriensieg/text-similarities-da019229c894) may be helpful for you.

Calculate the distance of the similarity, set a threshold to decide which one should be deleted.

1. pip install python-Levenshtein
2. Code

   import Levenshtein

   distance = Levenshtein.distance("content1", "content2")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: exactly. this is the solution i was looking for. Thank you very much